# How to get the value from an object

Tags: apex, map, sobject, fields

I have an object which gives me the following when I debug :-

```
{name=Baltmore, uid=abcdef00-acft-126a-8cfw-efihfcirffw}
```

I would like to get the uid as a string. I tried `agency.get('uid')` but this doesn't work.

My Code :-

```
List<Object> results = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(GetAgencies().getBody());
for (Object agency: results) {
    System.debug((Map<String, Object>)agency); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `List<Object> results = (List<Object>)` to `Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>)`

---

considering, you have the following JSON body: `'{ "name" : "Baltmore", "uid" : "abcdef00-acft-126a-8cfw-efihfcirffw"}`

```
String str = '{ "name" : "Baltmore", "uid" : "abcdef00-acft-126a-8cfw-efihfcirffw"}';
Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(str);
System.debug('results.get(uid):' + results.get('uid'));
//|DEBUG|results.get(uid):abcdef00-acft-126a-8cfw-efihfcirffw
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) tool to generate wrapper class to which response could be deserialized:

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public String name {get; set;}
    public String uid {get; set;}


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

to parse:

```
JSON2Apex result = JSON2Apex.parse(getAgencies().getBody());
System.debug('uid:' + result.uid );
```